# I am having trouble converting a for loop to a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I would like to convert the following for loop to a foreach loop, this is the for loop:

```
checkLetter(letter) {
    //give the letter class a variable named letters to have a reference to them
   var letters = $('.letter');

   for (var i=0; i < letters.length; i++) {
       console.log(letters[i].innerHTML);
        //if the phrase contains a letter from the phrases array return true, otherwise it will return false
       if(letter === letters[i].innerHTML) {
        console.log('this is true')
        return true
       }
       else return false
    }
}
```

and this is what I wrote for the `forEach` version:

```
checkLetter(letter) {
    //give the letter class a variable named letters to have a reference to them
    var letters = $('.letter');
    //loop through each letter using Foreach
    letters.forEach(letter)
    console.log(letters[i].innerHTML);
    //if the phrase contains a letter from the phrases array return true, otherwise it will return false
    if(letter === letters[i].innerHTML) {
        console.log('this is true')
        return true
    }
    else return false
}
```

However, I ended up getting the following error:

**letters.foreach is not a function**

could someone please help?

Comment: forEach is an array method. I suppose letters is a string.

Comment: Braces for forEach loop is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letters` is a jQuery object, not an array; to loop over a jQuery object, you'll either have to use a jQuery method, like `each`:

```
letters.each((i, letter) => {
  // do something with `letter`
```

or call `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  letters,
  letter => {
    // do something with `letter`
  }
);
```

Also note that your current `letters.forEach(letter)` doesn't make sense - `forEach` accepts a *callback function* as a parameter.

For what you're trying to achieve, though, it would be more appropriate to use `Array.prototype.some` to check if any if the items in `letters` fulfill the condition: `forEach` is more appropriate for generic iteration, when other array methods don't suffice:

```
checkLetter(letterToFind) {
  var letters = $('.letter');
  return Array.prototype.some.call(
    letters,
    letterElement => letterElement.textContent === letterToFind
  );
}
```

Or, less appropriate IMO but would still work, using jQuery's `each`:

```
checkLetter(letterToFind) {
  var letters = $('.letter');
  let foundLetter = false;
  letters.each((i, letterElement) => {
    if ($(letterElement).text() === letterToFind) {
      foundLetter = true;
    }
  });
  return foundLetter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach based on `forEach()` would not be a good fit for your problem as it will make "early returns" during your the `forEach()` loop difficult.

Perhaps you could consider using `some()` which returns true if an item in the iteration satisfies a provided condition:

```
return node.innerHTML === letter
```

Using `some()`, you could implement your `checkLetter()` function via the following:

```js
function checkLetter(letter) {
  
  // Query document for .letter nodes. This avoids the need for jQuery
  var letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');

  // Convert letters selection result to Array via Array.from, and 
  // then call some() to determine if at least one node satisfies
  // the match condition "node.innerHTML === letter"
  return Array.from(letters).some(function(node) {

    return node.innerHTML === letter
  })
}


console.log('Check A:', checkLetter('A'))
console.log('Check B:', checkLetter('B'))
console.log('Check Z:', checkLetter('Z'))
```

```html
<div class="letter">A</div>
<div class="letter">B</div>
<div class="letter">C</div>
<div class="letter">D</div>
```

Comment: I was able find a solution thanks to everyone who helped!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery .[each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$( ".letter" ).each(function( index ) {
if(letter === $( this ).html()) {
        console.log('this is true')
        return false; // this will stop the execution
       } 
});
```

Comment: This won't produce the correct results - the `$.each()` method does not return the result of the iteration callback - see the answer above for a correct solution based on the `$.each()` method :-) 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53698926/8526705

Comment: @DacreDenny I know that http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ is for array iteration and https://api.jquery.com/each/ is for jQuery Object iteration.By  #Erik L  in the question used :  var letters = $('.letter');  . But here is letters is actually a Dom element list not an Array. Isn't it?

Comment: In the OP, the function needs to return true if a match is found during iteration. Retuning true in `$.each` does not achieve this. Sorry typing on my phone so hard to elaborate with more detail, but re-read the jQuery docs regarding the return behavior of handler functions passed to `$.each` hope that helps :)

Comment: But I think this portion is ok. if(letter === $( this ).html()) {
        console.log('this is true') and the console.log will  print  the desired output. Als o he can use return = false to stop. See I have edited the answer. I think there is no doubt now :) .  I have tested this in my local PC.

Comment: have a look at the return behavior of `checkLetter()` in the OP - notice how the function itself is returning `true` or `false` depending on a match being found. The function isn't only about logging and early exiting from a for loop - it's about returning true if a match is found, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the loop answers have been given I am going to propose a different approach. I suggest that you convert all the matching nodes `.letter` into a string and use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to determine whether there is a match. Ex:

```js
function checkLetter(letter) {
  return $('.letter').text().indexOf(letter) > -1;
}

console.log('A', checkLetter('A'));
console.log('C', checkLetter('C'));
console.log('F', checkLetter('F'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="letter">A</span>
<span class="letter">B</span>
<span class="letter">C</span>
<span class="letter">D</span>
<span class="letter">E</span>
```